Como solucionar error del lector de pantalla android
Tengo este xml >
    <!-- Correo -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Correo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/email_et"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/correo"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

estoy publicando mi app en la play consola y me da este error:

Recomendación
Es posible que este elemento no tenga una etiqueta que pueda leer un lector de pantalla.

como lo puedo resolver? ya he agregado,
android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescTXVCorreo"

pero aun así me lo han devuelto,
cual sera el problema?
que me recomienda hacer?
de antemano muchas gracias

Agrega el email que te envió Google acerca del rechazo de tu app.
